# How to get a specific users array of data from a username input

Tags: angular, http, get

i'm trying to return a specific users data from my database. I'm calling for the entire users array with http.get, but i'm having trouble filtering to the username that was originally provided by the input box.

```
 login.component.ts
`this.loginService.loginUser().subscribe(data => {
  this.userUserName = data.find(users => users === this.userName);
  console.log(this.userUserName);`

 service.ts
`loginUser(): any {
  return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/users/allusers');

  }`
```

ERROR TypeError: data.find is not a function

Comment: ```data``` is a ```HttpResponse```. Your users should be in ```data.body```. Piece of advice : create some methods that use the searched login as a parameter : it will avoid retrieving all the users of the DB and then send all the users on client side. (performance issues)

Comment: Can I use the login parameter in the service.ts file? And if so, how could I add it to my http.get(‘users/all user data’)?

Answer (score 0):

To solve your error and to achieve this without retrieving all the users from db, here how I would do it :
service.ts

```js
getAllUsers(): Observable<HttpResponse<User[]>> {
  return this.http.get<User[]>('http://localhost:3000/users');
}

getUser(login: string): Observable<HttpResponse<User>> {
  return this.http.get<User>(`http://localhost:3000/users/${login}`);
}
```

and then in component.ts

```js
this.loginService.getUser(this.userName).subscribe((response:HttpResponse<User>) => {
  console.log(response.body.login);
});
```

About server side, here is an example with springboot

```java
    @GetMapping("/users")
    public ResponseEntity<List<User>> getAllUsers() {
        // Here : access db and returns all users
        return this.userService.getAllUsers();
    }

     @GetMapping("/users/{login}")
    public ResponseEntity<User> getUserFromLogin(@PathVariable String login) {
        // Here : access db and find the row related to the expected login
        return this.userService.findByLogin(login);
    }
```

NB :  please note that I have removed the `allusers` from the url and mapping because server side there would be an issue as `allusers` would be considered as a login